# ¿Qué significa "¿Quién se anima?" en castellano?

Tags: traducción

What would be the best translation for the aforementioned phrase in English? I have asked friends and they have trouble explaining the correct English translation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Who's up for it?
>
> Who's in?
>
> Any takers?

etc.

Comment: So in more of a slang way this is similar to saying "who's down?"

Comment: I suppose. There might be a generation gap between us :)